# Stdout/stderr redirects in start-stop-daemon

Tags: debian, bash

I'm trying to write `init` config that will redirect output of my daemon to two files (for stdout and stderr). The problem is, it's not working. I'm reading [this](http://linux.derkeiler.com/Mailing-Lists/Debian/2005-12/msg01053.html) right now.

So, I've done this shell script to test this approach. And it doesnt' work:

```
PATH=/sbin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/usr/bin
DESC="Seed kurokikaze starter"
#NAME=node
DAEMON="/etc/node-version/0.1.99/bin/node"
DAEMON_ARGS="/etc/seed/kurokikaze/server.js"
DAEMON_DIR="/etc/seed/kurokikaze"

APPLOG_FILE="/var/log/seed/kurokikaze"
ERRLOG_FILE="/var/log/seed/kurokikaze-err"

PIDFILE="/var/run/seeds/kurokikaze.pid"
SCRIPTNAME="/etc/seed-init/kurokikaze"

NCMD="exec $DAEMON $DAEMON_ARGS 1>>$APPLOG_FILE 2>>$ERRLOG_FILE"

start-stop-daemon -Sbmv --pidfile $PIDFILE --chdir ${DAEMON_DIR} --exec $DAEMON --startas /bin/sh -- $NCMD
```

But if you start this without wrapping daemon in separate shell, it works as intended (just without stderr/stdout redirects):

```
start-stop-daemon -Sbmv --pidfile $PIDFILE --chdir ${DAEMON_DIR} --exec $DAEMON -- ${DAEMON_ARGS}
```

The question is: why first script doesn't work? System is Debian Lenny, `start-stop-daemon` version is 1.14.29

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because of the order of expansion, you can't pass redirections in variables. Redirection is evaluated before word splitting.

See [BashFAQ/050](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050), [Shell Expansions](http://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/bash/bashref.html#SEC28) and [Redirections](http://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/bash/bashref.html#SEC39).

Comment: Yep, so just replace the last two lines with:

NCMD="exec $DAEMON $DAEMON_ARGS";start-stop-daemon -Sbmv --pidfile $PIDFILE --chdir ${DAEMON_DIR} --exec $DAEMON --startas /bin/sh -- $NCMD  1>>$APPLOG_FILE 2>>$ERRLOG_FILE

Comment: Will it redirect node streams or `start-stop-daemon`'s?

Comment: @Kuroki and @BMDan: That will redirect the output of `start-stop-daemon`.

Comment: Any way to listen only for daemon output (other of sh wrapper)?

Answer (score 1):

Your line in the script is:

```
start-stop-daemon -Sbmv --pidfile $PIDFILE --chdir ${DAEMON_DIR} --exec $DAEMON --startas /bin/sh -- $NCMD
```

So you are basically saying to exec `$DAEMON` using `$NCMD` as args. Try to change `$NCMD` to

```
"$DAEMON_ARGS 1>>$APPLOG_FILE 2>>$ERRLOG_FILE"
```

and see if it works.

If not, you will have to change your software to redirect `stdout` and `stderr` to files (maybe it already has a logging option). You can also write a *wrapper* script just to do the redirection but that is a little on the ugly side.

Answer (score 1):

Another way for that streams redirection using of [nohup](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nohup) like:

```
nohup ./bin/servicemix ./conf/servicemix.xml > log/nohup.log 2>&1 &
```